# Google map not showing without css part

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, google-maps, geolocation

i am working on demo code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>


<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7CfuQy1peyVRH0y2ejWQfXVq3_JMi1xE&callback=initMap">
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

and js file

```
    function initMap() {
alert("Inside initMap");
    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
```

if i am removing (from html file)

```
     <style>
        #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
```

then map is not showing but a error in console is coming (in image)[image]
 any body can please tell me how style or css can effect this
(with style tags)[image]

Comment: What error you are getting in the console?

Comment: Map needs to know parent element dimensions in order to scale itself properly. If you don't set them either implicitly or as percentage it can't build itself properly

Comment: If your div map container have not a real size the map is not displayed  this is a google maps mandatory feature ..

Comment: thank you all for giving proper reason for this, it was like itch in the mind